# How to create a modal that shows blog-posts in blogger homepage?

Tags: bootstrap-modal, blogger

I have a blogger website; in the homepage (index page) there are blog-posts (thumbnail, title, snippets and "view" button). I need to create a modal that pops-up when the "view" button is clicked. It should show blog-post title, image thumbnail and some other post details.
How to achieve that please ?

I tried java script but the modal shows only one blog-post when click on each "view" button.

[image]

```
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js'/>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Shop">view</button>

<div id="Shop" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="Shop" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" display="block">

  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content simpleCart_shelfItem">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><a expr:href='data:post.href'><data:post.title/></a></h4>
        </div>  
      </div> 
    </div> 

<script>
$('#Shop').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
  var title = &quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;;
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(title)
})
</script>
```